# How to make column iterative Dynamic Array Function?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, lambda

I'm trying to practice the new M365 Dynamic Array Function and thought of making a simple data profiler that iterates over each column and tells the count of blanks and count of Unique values.

[image]

I want to make it dynamic so that it iterates over each column in the range provided to `a` and gets me the counts.
I tried `BYCOL` but I got the Nested Array function.
Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Please provide your formula, sample data and expected output as text within your question - this makes it much easier to help you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I usually try to be as compact as I can go with formulas, but to try and tell the story as to what is happening here I have been basically as verbose as possible for educational purposes I guess:

[image]

Formula in `D1`:

```
=LET(Range,A1:B7,Headers,TAKE(Range,1),Data,DROP(Range,1),REDUCE({"Column Name","Blanks","Unique"},SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(Data)),LAMBDA(Accumulator,Iterator,LET(COL,INDEX(Data,,Iterator),VSTACK(Accumulator,HSTACK(INDEX(Headers,Iterator),COUNTBLANK(COL),ROWS(UNIQUE(TOCOL(COL,1)))))))))
```

To try and break it down:

- `Range` - A variable to hold the entire range of data, including your headers, therefor the only piece of formula you'd have to change;
- `Headers` - Use `TAKE()` to get the first row from given range;
- `Data` - Use `DROP()` to get only the body of data to work with;
- `REDUCE()` - We open an accumulator/stacker to start `VSTACK()`'ing using an accumulator and an current interator;

  - `Accumulator` - This is the current state at any given time in the iteration. Our starting array is given as the headers in your desired results;
  - `Iterator` - We have acquired an iterator by counting the amount of columns in our `Data` variable using `SEQUENCE()`;
  - Within each iteration we can `INDEX()` the correct header/column and `HSTACK()` our calculations, thus: `COUNTBLANK()` and `ROWS(UNIQUE(TOCOL()))`.

I hope this made sense when put in this way.

Two small remarks. You'll see the count of unique values differs to what you want for column `A`. If you really want the count to be 5, you can remove the `TOCOL()` nested in the `UNIQUE()` function. Either way, in it's current form this works on the assumption you'd not have completely empty columns in your `Data`.

Comment: Excellent! I need to look into `TAKE` and `REDUCE`. Thank you, @JvdV!

Comment: You are welcome. Please take note of the remarks I made at the bottom of my answer. @Joker

Comment: I did and you laid them out so well.

Comment: Master is all at its best. Thanks for the great explanation, Sir!!!